# SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK Documentation?

Tags: abap, saprfc

Where can I find the SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK online documentation?

A developer told me to download a zip file in this [issue](https://github.com/SAP/PyRFC/issues/89#issuecomment-447299033)

I can't believe that the docs are not available online. We live in the 21 century :-)

Where is the SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK **online** documentation?

Comment: You mean **freely** available. Not with SAP, you must have credentials, i.e. own a S-user to access most of SAP support resources.

Comment: @SandraRossi that is strange, since a lot of tools like PyRFC are available as open source from SAP. I have a S-user to access support resources. But it is annoying that you can't share the sources freely. This slows down communication and development. I hope this will change in the future.

Comment: the documentation (or at least part of it, don't know if there is a more comprehensive documentation somewhere else) is actually freely available (see: https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70ehp3/helpdata/en/48/a88c805134307de10000000a42189b/frameset.htm ). But quite often, if you want to download something from SAP SWDC, you need your S-User to do so. Generally, documentation should be on https://help.sap.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SAP NetWeaver 7.52

https://help.sap.com/viewer/753088fc00704d0a80e7fbd6803c8adb/7.52.0/en-US/48a88c805134307de10000000a42189b.html?q=SAP%20NetWeaver%20RFC%20SDK

Search help.sap.com for other NetWeaver versions:

https://help.sap.com/viewer/search?q=SAP%20NetWeaver%20RFC%20SDK&language=en-US&state=PRODUCTION&format=standard,html,pdf,others&product=SAP_NETWEAVER_AS_ABAP_752

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the following guides:

Part I -- RFC Client Programming

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/zz27Gg

Part II -- RFC Server Programming

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/9z27Gg

Part III -- Advanced Topics

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/x/FD67Gg

And for the C programmer, the Doxygen documentation is a valuable companion:
https://support.sap.com/en/product/connectors/nwrfcsdk.html --> Documentation in Doxygen format

Comment: SAP links are very short lived. The question you have answered looks off-topic as per Stack Overflow rules.